# Hybris 2105 - kyma integration

Tags: docker, sap-commerce-cloud, kyma

Hybris 2105 out of the box consists of kymaintegrationbackoffice and kymaintegrationservices. Does anyone have idea how to use these extensions to work with local kyma instance.

Answer (score 1):

They are just part of [SAP BTP extension](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/bad9b0b66bac476f8a4a5c4a08e4ab6b/033a3080ab4a4bd0bdb80b7afe381145.html?locale=en-US&version=v2105). With these extension you can create your own extensions on SAP BTP [Kyma Runtime](https://discovery-center.cloud.sap/serviceCatalog/kyma-runtime?region=all) side. Kyma is not a solution, it is application extend framework. You can find the installation step of this extension [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/bad9b0b66bac476f8a4a5c4a08e4ab6b/aee97a137e53460a87f5d6776f65b108.html?locale=en-US&version=v2105)

Maybe you need to ask more specific.

Comment: Hi mkysoft, May be you are not thinking in **SAP hybris** perspective. In my case kymaintegrationbackoffice and kymaintegrationservices are extensions in hybris. I wanted to know how to use these extensions for connecting with kyma.

Comment: I was added the extension link, you can found the installation step on left site: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/bad9b0b66bac476f8a4a5c4a08e4ab6b/aee97a137e53460a87f5d6776f65b108.html?locale=en-US&version=v2105

Answer (score 0):

So far i didn't find out any solution to integrate local kyma instance with sap commerce(hybris) but figured out it can be done using ngrok. I realized that it is far more easier to integrate local sap commerce with kyma runtime provided
by SAP BTP. Sap commerce suite **2105** and above versions have supporting extensions(kymaintegrationbackoffice,kymaintegrationservices) for integration with kyma.
I have followed the steps documented in below link.

https://help.sap.com/docs/BTP/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/83df31ad3b634c0783ced522107d2e73.html